# Fitting multiple linear regression in R: autocorrelated residuals

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression, autocorrelation, residuals

I'm trying to estimate a multiple linear regression in R with an equation like this:

```
regr <- lm(rate ~ constant + askings + questions + 0)
```

askings and questions are quarterly data time-series, constructed with `askings <- ts(...)`.

The problem now is that I got autocorrelated residuals. I know that it is possible to fit the regression using the gls function, but I don't know how to identify the correct AR or ARMA error structure which I have to implement in the gls function.

I would try to estimate again now with,

```
gls(rate ~ constant + askings + questions + 0, correlation=corARMA(p=?,q=?))
```

but I'm unfortunately neither an R expert nor an statistical expert in general to identify p and q.

I would be pleased If someone could give me a useful hint.
Thank you very much in advance!

Jo

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(rate, xreg=cbind(askings,questions))
```

That will fit the linear model as will as automatically identify an ARMA structure for the errors. It uses MLE rather than GLS, but they are asymptotically equivalent.

Comment: This is so helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If prediction is you purpose, you could fit a range of models over parameters:

```
expand.grid(p = 1:P, q = 1:Q)
```

where `P` and `Q` are the maximal AR(p) and MA(q) terms you wish to include and choose the best fitting model as determined by BIC.

`auto.arima()` in package **forecast** will help with this, but it can be coded easily by hand using `expand.grid()` and loop and the `arima()` function that comes with R.

The above is fitting on the residuals from a `gls()` with no `correlation` structure.

You could also do the whole thing by hand directly with `gls()` by just fitting lots of models for combinations of `p` and `q` and the in built `AIC()` function.

You could also plot the ACF (`acf()`) and partial ACF (`pacf()`) of the residuals from a linear model without correlation structure and use them to suggest the order of model required.